# Problems installing spaCy on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, installation, windows-8.1, spacy

I've read bunch of questions with this problem (not being able to install spaCy), but nothing seem to relate to what I'm experiencing. So I post this in pure desperation and here it goes:

I'm trying to install spacy trough pyCharm (and terminal) and it doesn't seem to work.

- installed Python 3.8
- deleted all other Python versions
- set the environment

here's the output that I get:

[image]

and:

[image]

Comment: Try python3.7 instead of python3.8. Python3.8 is very new and I'm not sure everything has been tested thoroughly yet. (In general, please cut and paste messages/errors as code blocks rather than images. They are much easier to read and search.)

Comment: I've tried python3.7 before and it didn't work since it said I needed 3.8...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what would require python3.8. I would recommend trying python3.7 and installing spacy in a new virtual environment.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick, I've tried a lot of things I've surely messed up something in the configuration and just supposed that 3.7 (67-bit version doesn't work).

Thanks! I feel like I owe you e-beer/cake (whatever you're more into).